# How to convert 2007 Docx files having (altchunk content) to PDF using java

Tags: java, html, pdf, docx4j

How to convert 2007 Docx files having altchunk content to PDF using java.

Is there any way to convert A docx file which has A html content (Altchunk) .
Into PDF using java

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
    .createPackage();
  MainDocumentPart mdp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

  WordprocessingMLPackage docxFile = WordprocessingMLPackage
    .load(new File("d:\\3\\1.docx"));
  MainDocumentPart mdp1 = docxFile.getMainDocumentPart();
  WordprocessingMLPackage pkgOut = mdp.convertAltChunks();
  // Display result
  System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(pkgOut
    .getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));

 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert your HTML to well formed XML.

Add docx4j-ImportXHTML to your path.

Then invoke [convertAltChunks()](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/JaxbXmlPartAltChunkHost.java#L164)

After that, your XHTML altChunks will be ordinary docx content, and you can convert the docx to PDF.

Comment: Please explain me .. how to invoke the above method .. i have implemented the code inside docx4j jar file and have tried below code.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
    .createPackage();
  MainDocumentPart mdp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

  WordprocessingMLPackage docxFile = WordprocessingMLPackage
    .load(new File("d:\\3\\1.docx"));
  MainDocumentPart mdp1 = docxFile.getMainDocumentPart();
  WordprocessingMLPackage pkgOut = mdp.convertAltChunks();
  // Display result
  System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(pkgOut
    .getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));

 }

Comment: But failed to convert docx altchunk content.

Comment: Add the code (formatted) to your question.  When you say "failed", in what way?  Was there an exception?  You'd better configure logging.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following ...

1.rebuild docx4j putting JaxbXmlPartAltChunkHost.class
2.run the below program.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .createPackage();
        MainDocumentPart mdp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        WordprocessingMLPackage docxFile = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(new File("d:\\3\\1.docx"));
        MainDocumentPart mdp1 = docxFile.getMainDocumentPart();
        WordprocessingMLPackage pkgOut = mdp1.convertAltChunks();
        // Display result
        System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(pkgOut
                .getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));
```

it works fine....

Thank you